# UWP , Play sound file on Desktop?

Tags: uwp, mediaelement

I am tring to open a Wav-file on desktop to play the sound.
Is this possible in UWP application ?

```
var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        //StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var uri = new System.Uri(filename);
        var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
        StorageFile storageFolder = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        var file = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(filename) as IStorageFile;

        if (file != null)
        {
            StorageFile soundfile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            mediaElement.SetSource(await soundfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), soundfile.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
```

here is my file name. it's full path.

```
D:\develop\visualstudio2\local\sound\sound1.wav
```

Here is my requirement.

1. Open a file with filepicker ( I success )
2. Save path to Sqlite database.
3. Restart application.
4. get file path from Sqlite database.
5. play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a wav file at the root of your application "media/test.wav"

```
var element = new MediaElement();
 var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("media");
 var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("test.wav");
 var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
 element.SetSource(stream, "");
 element.Play();
```

Comment: I want to make a option that User can switch sound file to their favorite. then, I can not have the Wav file on installed directory. Is this possible on UWP ?   See my update .

Comment: See this ref it may help you :  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-task-snippets/blob/master/tasks/Play-sound-once-or-looped.md

Comment: ms-appx:///Assets/test.mp3, Is this Asset folder ?   I want to play a file on c:\abc.wav , Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I success !

Here is step

1. First pick a wav-file with PickSingleFileAsync
2. Copy the file to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
3. save the file name to Sqlite database. ( not include full path )
4. Play the file ( save LocalFolder ).

OK, let's go.

First , Pick a file.

```
public async void Click_SettingCommonPathSoundFile1()
    {
        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // save to the file name to Sqlite at here.
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);

        }
    }
```

and play later.

```
    public async void Click_SettingCommonPathSoundFile1Play()
    {
       // get file name from database.
        await playit("sound1.wav");

    }
```

and..

```
    private async Task playit(string filename)
    {

        var element = new MediaElement();
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        element.SetSource(stream, "");
        element.Play();
```

}